# Player can't move after restarting

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, unity-game-engine

I created a simple Scene with a `SceneManager` implemented as a Singleton.

When using only that scene, It works flawless.

Then I added a restart button and problems started.

Initially I had some `NullReferenceException` Issue: I found the cause, the problem was due to some arrays of the singleton instance that were not cleared; the script found an array with x elements, but all of them were null references. So I added some code in the `Start()` function in order to check if the array is empty or not. If it isn't I clear the array (before the start the array must be empty, if it is not, it's an array of null references).

After solving all the `NullReferenceException` issues (that drove the application to crash), I am still not able to make the application run after restart.

The new issue is that the player, whose `GameObject` is defined in the scene as a `GameObject` with a `CapsuleCollider`, a `RigidBody` and a `RigidBodyFPSController`, doesn't move after restarting. I think it's a problem with the attached script that maybe are not created again after restarting.

Any idea?

Comment: Where are you getting the nullpointer? I just tested that code and it works just fine.... Could you give more details about your issue?

Comment: @CabrraWhat code? I can't find any in his post

Comment: he edited the post. You can check the original post clicking the "edited" link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Application.LoadLevel("your_scene");
```

Add this to the restart_function/code that you have.
This should reset the level/scene to the original that was loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can initialize `array` first with game objects and after `restart` it has fixed reference in array that is first defined so it point to the old objects that are now destroy, and the script trying to referenced it.
reinitialize objects with creating array `null` and assigning value on it.
or `application.load("scene_name")`